# Selecting a Dropdown List Option in Google Forms Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

we have a hudge database of people who will receive financial help on the COVID-19 situation. I'm trying to create a VBA code that allows me to fill the Google Form that will be used to collect the data: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfmOe5my6a0OwGj5jOY1hFNreZCjDGLuK7qllEr18tlGxys-w/viewform.

The problem is, there's a dropdown option in this form, and for some reason I can't select any of the options in the list. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfmOe5my6a0OwGj5jOY1hFNreZCjDGLuK7qllEr18tlGxys-w/viewform"
    IE.Visible = True

    IE.document.all("entry.2084723474").InnerText = "Teste Nome"
    IE.document.all("entry.1921177593").InnerText = "37121851890"

Set HTML = IE.document
Set elements = HTML.getElementsByclassName("quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList")

For Each element In elements
    If element.className = "quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList" Then
        element.Click
    End If
Next element

Dim e
For Each e In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.InnerText = "Paraisópolis (SP)" Then

        ' Found the <span>.
        e.parentelement.Click

        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

In this part I found the option on the list, but when I send the command to Click in it's parent element, nothig happens:

```
Dim e
For Each e In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.InnerText = "Paraisópolis (SP)" Then

        ' Found the <span>.
        e.parentelement.Click

        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

That's it, any help will be very usefull to me in this moment. And I'm sorry for my terrible english.

Answer (score 0):

Google docs are not using VBA. What you have there is javascript. 
Not sure which dropdown should fill what. Please specify.

Comment: This should be a comment. The OP is using VBA to automate browser which is perfectly fine in many cases.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I don't know how to use javascript, that's why I'm trying to access the form page using IE with excel. The element that I'm trying to change is '<div class="quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList" jsname="d9BH4c" role="presentation" > ==$0'

Answer (score 0):

By using the F12 developer tools to check the selected DropDownList option, we can see that the DropDownList options could be selected by add/remove the "isSelected" class style. Please check the following screenshot:

[image]

Besides, from the above image, we can also find the DropDownList option contains a "data-value" attribute which equals the DropDownList option's text. So, we could use it to find the options, and then add/remove the class value.

Please refer to the following sample code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfmOe5my6a0OwGj5jOY1hFNreZCjDGLuK7qllEr18tlGxys-w/viewform")

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        IE.document.all("entry.2084723474").InnerText = "Teste Nome"
        IE.document.all("entry.1921177593").InnerText = "37121851890"

        Dim itemlist As Object

        Set itemlist = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption")

        Dim selectedvalue As String

        selectedvalue = "Cap*"

        If Len(itemlist) > 0 Then
            For Each Item In itemlist
                'Debug.Print Item.getAttribute("data-value")
                'check whether the DropDownList option starts with the selected value.
                If Item.getAttribute("data-value") Like selectedvalue Then
                    Item.classList.Add ("isSelected")
                    Item.setAttribute "aria-selected", "true"
                    Item.setAttribute "tabindex", "0"
                Else
                    Item.classList.Remove ("isSelected")
                    Item.setAttribute "aria-selected", "false"
                    Item.setAttribute "tabindex", "-1"
                End If
            Next Item
        End If
    End With
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

[Note] Since the DropDownList option contains different characters, might be the VBA not identify it. More details, please check the following Debug result. So, in the above code, I will find the DropDownList options using the first three characters.

VBA Debug result:

[image]

After running the above VBA script, the result as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Zhi, thanks a lot for your time and patience. The code sems to work perfectly but when I click the "Send" button, the form returns beahves like if the dropdown wasn't selected. I'm really thinking in try to use Sendkeys to select the options.

Comment: @FernandoFeio, I have modified above code, we should also change the `aria-selected` and `tabindex` attribute value. For the selected option, we need to change their value to `True` and `0`.  After modifying, the code works well when click the submit button, please check it.